# Etymology of "iron" - semantic change

Tags: etymology

I have run into something weird about the etymology of this word.

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/iron#Etymology) gives some details. It claims that it descends from PIE  *h₁ésh₂r̥ (blood) via Proto-Celtic, and cites two sources to back this up.

Is it named after molten iron being likened to blood? What mystery! Also, Wiktionary also gives an alternate derivation, *ish₂ros ‎(“supernatural, holy”).

Is the  *h₁ésh₂r̥ etymology sound?

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* says that while it is not impossible that the Celtic and Germanic bases are cognate, it is more likely that the Germanic base was borrowed < Celtic in prehistory, alongside the introduction of iron technology to northern Europe.

The *OED* lists three derivatives for the underlying form:

> (i) a derivative of the Indo-European base of ***ore n.<sup>2</sup>***;
>
> (ii) a derivative of the Indo-European base of ancient Greek ***ἱερός* strong** (probably a further sense of ***ἱερός* holy, sacred**: see hiero- *comb. form*);
>
> (iii) a derivative of the Indo-European base of ancient Greek ***ἔαρ , εἶαρ* blood** (on account of the colour of iron oxide, especially as seen in iron ore);

But the *OED* says that these all pose phonological problems and attempts have been made to resolve these problems by suggesting transmission via Illyrian. Borrowing into either Germanic or Celtic from a non-Indo-European language has also been suggested.

The book *Language and History in the Early Germanic World* (By D. H. Gree) has further discussion on the origin of the word. It is concluded that the Germanic word for 'iron' is unlikely to be native, but rather borrowed from a non-Germanic language.

> The closeness of the Celtic isoglosses and the absence of any other counterparts suggests that this source was Celtic, a conclusion borne out by the significant  fact of accent doublets in both Celtic and Germanic<sup>59</sup>, as well as by the linguistic evidence for the dominance of Celtic iron-working over Germania.
>
> <sub><sup>59</sup> Birkhan (1970), 141.</sub>

Comment: Further is unknown? Nobody got ahold of those two sources Wiktionary used? I'll open up discussion at Wiktionary if nothing turns up.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost: You can find further information in the book [*Language and History in the Early Germanic World (By D. H. Gree)*](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Language_and_History_in_the_Early_German.html?id=RONb2alF0rEC).